# Error: Uncaught (in promise): BraintreeError: options.authorization is required when instantiating a client

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, braintree

I am actually trying to implement braintree using Angular with asp.net core. But i am facing an issue, I don't understand how to solve it. I am follwing this [article](https://medium.com/@debojyoti.chakraborty95/getting-started-with-braintree-payment-gateway-hosted-fields-in-angular-7-cdad73f2886e). I am using version 14 of angular. I have doing exactly the same as mentioned article. I don't know which authorization it is demanding. when i run the application, in the braintree UI, I failed to input Card Number ,Expiration date,CVV maybe for this error. here is my code:-

app.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as braintree from 'braintree-web';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paypal',
  templateUrl: './paypal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paypal.component.css']
})
export class PaypalComponent implements OnInit {

  CToken: any;
  hostedFieldsInstance: braintree.HostedFields;
  cardholdersName: string;
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getToken();
    this.createBraintreeUI();
    
  }

    getToken() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/paypal').subscribe({
      next: response => this.CToken = response,
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })
    console.log(this.CToken);
  }



  createBraintreeUI() {
    braintree.client.create({
      authorization: this.CToken
    }).then((clientInstance) => {
      braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: clientInstance,
        styles: {
          // Override styles for the hosted fields
        },
        

       
        fields: {
          number: {
            selector: '#card-number',
            placeholder: '1111 1111 1111 1111'
          },
          cvv: {
            selector: '#cvv',
            placeholder: '111'
          },
          expirationDate: {
            selector: '#expiration-date',
            placeholder: 'MM/YY'
          }
        }
      }).then((hostedFieldsInstance) => {

        this.hostedFieldsInstance = hostedFieldsInstance;

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('focus', (event) => {
          const field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
        });

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('blur', (event) => {
          const field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
        });

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('empty', (event) => {
          const field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
        });

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('validityChange', (event) => {
          const field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
          if (field.isPotentiallyValid) { 
            
          } else {
           
          }
          
        });
      });
    });
  }


   // Tokenize the collected details so that they can be sent to your server
   tokenizeUserDetails() {
    this.hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize({cardholderName: this.cardholdersName}).then((payload) => {
      console.log(payload);
     console.log("Bro! this is payload!!!"+payload.nonce);
      // submit payload.nonce to the server from here
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      // perform custom validation here or log errors
    });
  }

 


}
```

app.compoment.html

```
 <form id="cardForm">
    <div class="panel">
      <header class="panel__header">
        <h1>Card Payment</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="panel__content">
        <div class="textfield--float-label">
          <!-- Begin hosted fields section -->
          <label class="hosted-field--label" for="card-number"><span class="icon">
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M20 4H4c-1.11 0-1.99.89-1.99 2L2 18c0 1.11.89 2 2 2h16c1.11 0 2-.89 2-2V6c0-1.11-.89-2-2-2zm0 14H4v-6h16v6zm0-10H4V6h16v2z"/></svg></span> Card Number 
          </label>
          <div id="card-number" class="hosted-field"></div>
          <!-- End hosted fields section -->
        </div>
          <div class="custom-name">
            <label class="hosted-field--label" for="cardholder-name" name="cardholderName">
            <span class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1S9.9 9.16 9.9 8s.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1H5.9V17c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1M12 4C9.79 4 8 5.79 8 8s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
              </span>
              Cardholder's Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. JOHN DOE" class="name-custom-input" [(ngModel)]="cardholdersName" name="cardholderName"/>
    </div>
        <div class="textfield--float-label">
          <!-- Begin hosted fields section -->
          <label class="hosted-field--label" for="expiration-date">
             <span class="icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M9 11H7v2h2v-2zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm2-7h-1V2h-2v2H8V2H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 20c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16H5V9h14v11z"/></svg>
           </span>
            Expiration Date</label>
          <div id="expiration-date" class="hosted-field"></div>
          <!-- End hosted fields section -->
        </div>
        <div class="textfield--float-label">
          <!-- Begin hosted fields section -->
          <label class="hosted-field--label" for="cvv">
            <span class="icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"/></svg>
              </span>
              CVV</label>
          <div id="cvv" class="hosted-field"></div>
          <!-- End hosted fields section -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="panel__footer">
        <input type="button" value="Pay" (click)="tokenizeUserDetails();" class="pay-button"/>
      </footer>
    </div>
  
  </form>
```

Backend

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
...

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> client_token()
        {
            var gateway =  _braintreeService.GetGateway();
            var clientToken =  gateway.ClientToken.generate();
            return  clientToken;
        }
```

here is my error in console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): BraintreeError: options.authorization is required when instantiating a client.
    Angular 16
    4431 main.ts:11
    Webpack 7
        __webpack_require__
        __webpack_exec__
        <anonymous>
        O
        <anonymous>
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
core.js:6498
    Angular 3
    RxJS 5
    Angular 18
    4431 main.ts:11
    Webpack 7
```

[image]

I am a beginner. how to resolve this issue. or any alternative implementation? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check order of asynchronous requests.**

It appears you're not including your Braintree token in your request.

This is likely happening because you're making one asynchronous request before another completes.

A simple way to fix this would be to move the call to `this.createBraintreeUI()` inside the response to you token request. That way you would only make the second request after the first completes.

Something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getToken();    
  }

  getToken() {
    this.http.get('https://localhost:5001/api/paypal').subscribe({
      next: response => { 
        console.log(this.CToken);
        this.CToken = response;
        this.createBraintreeUI(); 
      },
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })

  }
```

There may be more issues, as this is a complex integration with Braintree, but if you check that `console.log()` statement you have and it's showing your token, and the token looks correct, then you're on the right path.

(For instance, you might have another problem where you can't pass `authorization: this.CToken` there in the first line of your `this.createBraintreeUI()` function. You might have to set `authorization` to a property of `this.CToken`. So look at the console.log statement showing your token and see if it looks correct. )

Answer (score -1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vyw6.png

```
import Permissions from 'react-redux-permissions';
```

**First I use**

```
<Permissions allowed={[]}>
```

**Fix**

```
<Permissions allowed={['']}>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/to6tV.png

**Second Way**

check condition inside and write on

```
<Permissions></Permissions>
```

Example:

```
    Wrong

  const permission = ['show'] || []

  `{name === 'About' &&
     <Permissions allowed={permission}>
      {show === true && <Component />}
     </Permissions>
   }`

  Correct

 `{name === 'About' && show === true &&
   <Permissions allowed={'show'}>
     <Component />
   </Permissions>
  }`
```

Comment: How is this answer relevant?